# WCF web service works on localhost, but not on specific ip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, iis

i have wcf webservice.It works  on localhost:55077 but when i try to communicate with a spesific ip like 192.168.1.103:80, it does not work... Here are some screen shots...Thanks all ...

[image: Control]
[image: ip dependencies]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i found an answer :
You can change the ApplicationPoolIdentity from IIS7 -> Application Pools -> Advanced Settings. AdvancedSettings

Under ApplicationPoolIdentity you will find local system. This will make your application run under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, which is an existing login for the database by default.

Answer (score 0):

> It works on localhost:55077

Is it hosted on IIS express ?

Per screenshot and port configured, looks you want to host on IIS server. Modify your endpoint address and host on local IIS.

Comment: Yes Rahul, i hosted it on iis express. When i test it on Telerik Fiddler, localhost works, ip does not...

Comment: can you check if you can map localhost to IP:192.168.1.103:80 in host.config file ?

Comment: Error 404.8 Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.